# PageFactory Error with Hello World, Interceptor.php

Tags: magento2, factory

Working on the Hello World example here:
alanstorm.com/magento_2_mvvm_mvc

I'm on the "Passing off to the View" step but I get an error with the World.php file when I refresh the page as instructed:

[image]

My world.php file is cut & pasted from the example.

The error mentions a "Interceptor.php" but there is no file by that name in the folder the error mentions.

[image]

Please advise and thanks.

Comment: The interceptor is auto-generated in var/generation folder, but you should not care about that. The problem originates from somewhere else. Please post in the question the contents of the `Controller/Hello/World.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are in `developer` mode.

Try one of the following **from your Magento root**:

- `php bin/magento cache:flush`
- `rm -Rf var/generation/*`

Sometimes, when you change a class constructor, you may have something left in your Magento's cache or autogenerated files. It happened to me several times.

Comment: Thank you @RiccardoT

The commands did not fix it for me but you reminded me to run through all my flushing and setup:upgrade commands:

php56 bin/magento setup:upgrade

php56 bin/magento module:status

php56 bin/magento cache:flush

php56 bin/magento list

rm -rf var/cache/*

rm -rf var/di/*

rm -rf var/generation/*

rm -rf var/page_cache/*